# Creating a javascript variable using another variable as a counter

Tags: javascript, variables

Say I want something like this:

```
var i = 0;

for (i upto 100) {
    var x+i = "This is another variable altogether";
    i++;
}
```

The javascript interpreter would see:

```
var x = "This is another variable altogether";
var x1 = "This is another variable altogether";
var x2= "This is another variable altogether";
var x3 = "This is another variable altogether";
var x4 = "This is another variable altogether";
```

Can I use a variable counter to increment the name of the variable so I have distinct variables altogether?

Comment: Why not use an associative array instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, yes.

If you're operating in the global scope which I suspect you are, you can do this:

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
  window["x"+i]="This is another variable altogether";
}

console.log(x1);
```

You should however be doing this kind of thing with an array, so:

```
var arr=[];
for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
  arr[i]="This is another variable altogether";
}

console.log(arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use distinct variables for that. Give a try to Array:

```
var arr = [];
...
arr.push('my var');
```

or object:

```
var ob = {};
...
ob[counter] = 'my var';
```

Comment: Instead of `arr[arr.length]` use `arr.push()`.

Comment: True that, I thought I read somewhere arr[arr.length] is faster but it seems it's not. Edited.

Comment: It wasn't concerned with speed, I just figured `a.push` is less confusing.